# angular uib-tabset not activate tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
  <div ng-show="isAppLoading" ng-cloak ng-controller="accListMainCtrl as vm" style="height:100%;">
    <h4>{{vm.dlg.active}}</h4>
    <uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab heading="Accounts list tree" ng-click="vm.load(1)" active="vm.dlg.active == 1"></uib-tab>
      <uib-tab heading="Accounts data grid" ng-click="vm.load(2)" active="vm.dlg.active == 2"></uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>

    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>
```

I set vm.dlg.active = 2, but second tab not active. Even when I set secont tab active="true", it not activated.

[image]

Comment: which version of `angular-ui` lib you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active` is a property of `uib-tabset` directive, not of `uib-tab`, see [doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs); try with

`<uib-tabset active="vm.dlg.active">`

Comment: this is correct but for versions 1.2.0+. see [docs@1.1.2](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.1.2/#/tabs) says `active` is for `uib-tab` :)